# Can we judge closedness of vitali set?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am not able to judge whether the vitali set is closed or not( in its parent set or u can say reals).....
Since it is 'mainly ' a subset of irrationals(except one rational representative) and irrationals are not closed subset of reals....I believe(am not sure) vitali set is not closed.....
But if I construct a set by taking irrational representatives in such a way that these form a sequence with 0(or any rational) as the limit point and the rational representative to be the same limit point.......then can I say that this set is closed???
M very confused.....kindly help me understand this concept.....
Any help will be heartily appreciated.....

Comment: Closed sets are definitely Lebesgue measurable, so Vitali sets are never closed (nor open, nor $G_\delta$, nor...)

Comment: Yea....u r ryt....but how can u prove directly that vitali set is not closed?

Comment: I agree that closed set is borel and every borel set is measurable.......but I want to conclude the other way..... That vitali set is closed......without considering its measurability......

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you really wanted to, my idea would be to notice that a Vitali set will contain just one rational element (provided the set you generated it from contains a rational element, of course). So in principle you could try to prove that there is a sequence converging to some other rational number. But this will be  trick because a Vitali set is a fundamentally nonconstructive object.

Comment: Yaa....but if I include that rational number also then will it not be closed?

Comment: And if then it becomes closed then it will be measurable.......but this is not so....  That means it should still not be closed............nd how could we conclude it........acc to me it will be closed........

Comment: You can only include one rational number for it to be a Vitali set. Of course, a Vitali set is even nastier than this, since a Vitali set unioned with the rationals will still be nonmeasurable, hence non-closed. I think you may be misunderstanding just how "jagged" a Vitali set actually is.

Comment: It's not clear to me........U mean to say if I add something to a set , the behaviour of the two sets will remain the same?

Comment: May be I am missing some important detail.......kindly help me.........

Comment: Let me make up a term for the moment: the "pseudo-boundary" of a set A is $\overline{A} \setminus A$. A Vitali set $V$ can only contain one rational number. So you might hope to directly show that $V$ is not closed by showing that there is a rational number in the pseudo-boundary (because somehow intuitively a Vitali set is rather "spread out" over the interval in which it was constructed).

Comment: (Cont.) But even if you consider $V \cup \mathbb{Q}$, this set is still not measurable, because if it were then $(V \cup \mathbb{Q}) \cap \mathbb{Q}^c=V$ would be measurable. Thus there are also *irrational* elements of the pseudo-boundary of $V$. Identifying these will not be so simple.

Comment: At any rate, I still don't know why you would want to directly show that a set whose existence is *fundamentally nonconstructive* is not closed using only the definition.

Comment: M sorry......m not familiar with these notations........$V\cup\mathbb{Q}$.......and......$(V\cup\mathbb{Q})\cap\mathbb{Q}^c=V$.....can u plz simplify them......if possible......in terms of complements ,union or whatever they mean.......

Comment: ...You're doing measure theory, you should be familiar with $\mathbb{Q}$ (the rationals), $\cup$ (union), and $\cap$ (intersection). You might not use $\mathbb{Q}^c$, which I'm using to denote the irrationals.

Comment: Thanks for ur help......nd giving me ur precious time nd importance.......May be I want some tym to understand.........but anyway, thanks for ur help nd support.........

Comment: @Ian For what it's worth, I think this is a good question - it's fun to try to come up with a "direct" proof that the Vitali set isn't closed. And I think it's neat to note that it's not entirely trivial! As another example of this, the easiest way I can think of to show that a Bernstein set isn't Borel is to use the perfect set property, and even for closed sets that's not trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed a concrete proof, which avoids measure (although it does use the Baire category theorem).

---

Let's talk about a Vitali set $V$ in $\mathbb{R}$, rather than in $[0, 1]$, for simplicity (so $V$ is a set of reals such that for each $r\in\mathbb{R}$, there is *exactly one* $s\in V$ with $s-r\in\mathbb{Q}$).

Consider the function $f_V$ associated to $V$, defined as $f_V(r)=s-r$ where $s$ is the unique element of $V$ such that $r-s\in\mathbb{Q}$. Note that we'll always have $f_V(r)\in\mathbb{Q}$, and $f_V(r)+r\in V$ for all $r$.

We claim - and will justify this below - that for some $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ and some nonempty interval $(a, b)$, the set $X=f_V^{-1}(q)\cap (a, b)$ is dense in $(a, b)$. If so, then:

- Note that for each $r\in X$, we have $r+q\in V$.
- If $V$ is closed, this means that $(a+q, b+q)\subseteq V$ (since $\{x+q: x\in X\}$ is contained in $V$ and is dense in $(a+q, b+q)$).
- But $(a+q, b+q)$ contains many distinct rationals - a contradiction.

---

So how do we prove the existence of such $q, a, b$? It comes down to the following fact:

> If $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$, then there is some $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ and nontrivial interval $(a, b)$ such that $g^{-1}(q)\cap (a, b)$ is dense in $(a, b)$.

And this is just the [Baire category theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem): that $\mathbb{R}$ isn't the union of countably many [nowhere-dense sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_dense_set).

Comment: From the comments above, it might be the case that you are unfamiliar with some of the notation I've used; if so, let me know and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur proof......it is a nyc proof according to me.......thank u vry much.........

Comment: The Cantor set is uncountable and nowhere dense, therefore looking at cardinality is not enough. However the argument with the Baire category theorem is really nice and does the job.

Comment: @Del Aigh, wow, not sure how I screwed that up - thanks! Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more "high-level" proof.

If $\lambda^*$ is the Lebesgue outer-measure, the set of all $\lambda^*$-measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak{M}$ which contains the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{
B}$ generated by the Euclidean topology $\mathcal{T}_e$ on $\mathbb{R}$. In other words we have,
$$\mathcal{T}_e\subset \mathcal{B}\subset\mathfrak{M}.$$
Since $V$ is not $\lambda^*$-measurable, then $V\not\in\mathfrak{M}$ which means $V$ is not open.
Also $V^c\not\in\mathfrak{M}\;$(otherwise $V\in \frak{M}$, a contradictoin), so $V^c$ is not open and hence $V$ is not closed.